# $ x^{2}- x- 4+ \frac{4\left ( x- 1 \right )^{2}}{\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}+ x+ 1}> 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

Solve the equation
$$x^{3}+ x+ 6= 2\left ( x+ 1 \right )\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}$$
The only answer is $x= 1$ so
I have rewritten it to
$$\left ( x- 1 \right )\left ( x^{2}- x- 4 \right )= 2\left ( x+ 1 \right ) \left (\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}- x- 1   \right )= 2\left ( x+ 1 \right )\frac{3+ 2x- x^{2}- \left ( x+ 1 \right )^{2}}{\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}+ x+ 1}= \frac{-4\left ( x+ 1 \right )^{2}\left ( x- 1 \right )}{\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}+ x+ 1}\Leftrightarrow \left ( x- 1 \right ) \left ( x^{2}- x- 4+ \frac{4\left ( x- 1 \right )^{2}}{\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}+ x+ 1} \right ) = 0$$
I need to prove $$ x^{2}- x- 4+ \frac{4\left ( x- 1 \right )^{2}}{\sqrt{3+ 2x-x^{2}}+ x+ 1}>  0 $$
Who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: 5 votes and 5 stars over 11 views? A group wants to get their homework done :P

Comment: That's not true. $x=1$ and the entire expression yields $-4$. Since at $x=3$ the expression becomes $6$, there must be another root. Also note that the expression is only valid for $x\in(-1,3]$

Comment: @MrRipstein I upvoted due to OP's effort in this question, and I don't belong to the "group".

Comment: By bad then @GNUSupporter. In any case, I didn't say it as a bad thing, I think it is nice if it makes a group of people involved in math.exchange

Comment: I run this equation through WolframAlpha and I see that it's actually not always positive. Please tell me if I'm wrong. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+x+-+4+%2B+(4(x-1)%5E2)%2F(sqrt(3+%2B+2x+-+x%5E2)+%2B+x+%2B+1)

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2nlvoldnwc

Answer (score 3):

Let $t=x-1$ and rewrite the equation like this

$$ t^3+3t^2+4t+8 = 2(t+2)\sqrt{4-t^2}$$

We see that $t=0$ (and so $x=1$) is a solution. Let us show it is the only one.
We also see that $t\in[-2,2]$. Now it is easy to see that $y=4t+8$ is tangent at $f(t) = t^3+3t^2+4t+8$. Let's prove that for all $t\in[-2,2]$ we have:

$$ 2(t+2)\sqrt{4-t^2} \leq 4t+8$$
If $t=-2$ both sides are equal so let's $t>-2$. Then $t+2>0$ so we have
$$ \sqrt{4-t^2} \leq 2  $$
which is true.
Since $$f(t) > 4t+8\geq  2(t+2)\sqrt{4-t^2}$$ for each $t\in[-2,2]\setminus \{0\}$ we see that $t=0$ is the only solution.